# Keeping 3 digits significant figure on Pandas with different currencies and removing 0s

Tags: python, pandas

I am web scraping exchange rates.
But I don't need a long significant figure.
Only 3-4 sig fig would be necessary.
Since all currency exc rate from USD to other currencies are different, I can't do it by the decimal points. (ex. Cambodian Riel KHR would give me 4083.000 instead of 4083)

```
def round_to_1(x):
    return round(x, 4-int(floor(log10(abs(x))))-1)

df['Exchange Rate'] = df['Exchange Rate'].apply(round_to_1)
```

Did the trick but leaves zeroes at the end.

And tried

```
df['Exchange Rate'] = df['Exchange Rate'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
```

to solve the problems but it doesn't seem to work perfectly.

Also heard that even though this is not a huge data, apply method is slow.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import log10, floor

def round_to_1(x):
    return round(x, 4-int(floor(log10(abs(x))))-1)

res = requests.get("https://www.exchange-rates.org/currentRates/P/USD")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table', {"class":"table table-fixedX table-exchange table-striped table-hover"}) 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df['Convert To'] = df['Convert To'].str[:-3] + ' ' + df['Convert To'].str[-3:]
df['Exchange Rate'] = df['Exchange Rate'].apply(round_to_1)
#df['Exchange Rate'] = df['Exchange Rate'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
df
```

Current output is

[image: current output]

But the expected output is

[image: expected output]

1. Is there a better/efficient way to have 4 sig fig instead of the apply function?
2. How do I get rid of 0s at the end?

Comment: Please post an example of input and your expected outptut to better illustrate your problem

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
df['Exchange Rate'] = df['Exchange Rate'].round(n).apply(lambda x: '{0:g}'.format(float(x)))
```

for `n` decimal places with trailing zeros removed.

Regarding performance concerns, under the hood `.apply` is merely a loop over the axis, so its time complexity is linear in number of elements of said axis.